# Gráfico de barras apiladas con paneles

Tags: excel

Hice este gráfico en R, usando la librería `ggplot2`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La revista a la que se envió el artículo que incluye este gráfico requiere que se envíen los datos y el gráfico hechos en Excel. Con los datos no hay problema, los pude exportar a una planilla de Excel. Pero no encuentro la manera de reproducir el gráfico.

En Excel pude hacer un gráfico de barras apiladas horizontales, pero no hacer los paneles. Por paneles entiendo hacer "subgráficos" separando una o más series, también los llaman gráficos Trellis.

Entonces las preguntas:

1. ¿Hay alguna manera directa de hacer un gráfico de barras apiladas con paneles en Excel?
2. ¿Hay algún workaround para que al menos se vea así? Lamentablemente editarlo en otro programa no es una opción, la revista solicita que el gráfico sea editable en Excel. Me parece absurdo, pero es así.

Desde [aquí](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZXOhIXZlmWHt6jDhq54rLWskKXNK8dggvxX) se pueden descargar los datos, es un Excel creado con la librería `writexl` de R desde un data.frame. Los datos ya están pivoteados de una forma que creo que es conveniente para hacer el gráfico.

Agradezco de antemano su atención.

Comment: Que manada de vagos, dizque Excel para una revista. Deberían poder trabajar con una imagen que generes de alta resolución (si es que ese es el problema). Déjame ver si puedo ayudar...

Comment: En esta revista son ultra especiales. Les enviamos toda la investigación reproducible: datos, código, tablas y gráficos. No, el área de diseño tiene una plantilla en Excel, así Excel tendrá que ser. Gracias, ojalá haya alguna forma de hacerlo porque estos gráficos son el núcleo del análisis cuanti del paper

Comment: Aunque R sea un lenguaje de programación; ***excel no lo es*** ... a lo sumo imagino que no podrás mostrar el grafico tal cual pudiste hacer en **R** lo recomendable es hacerlo según los grafico que excel te soporta y que son los que espera recibir la revista... el problema de esta publicación es que estas claramente buscando ayuda a un problema que no es de programación ... es de Ofimática ... No estoy seguro de que exista un sitio en SE que de soporte a lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque Intentar llevar un Grafico generado por programación a ***Excel*** Utilizando las Herramientas de Office no es un problema de Programación o que se pueda Resolver Mediante Programación; a menos que se haga con un macro; y dado el escenario por el usuario no seria lo conveniente o esperado para la revista.

Comment: ahora no me quiero ir sin aportarte algo ya que tu pregunta es interesante y te voy a dar tu like ... puedes validar si utilizando `reticulate`; puedes obtener un excel con un grafico nativo mas cercano a lo que buscas??? este es el link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61065836/17161735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si pudiste solucionar tu problema, pero lamentablemente, en Excel, que yo sepa, no se pueden crear matrices de gráficos como en R ni igual de complejos.

La única solución que pude encontrar es crear dos conjuntos de datos separados (Conservador vs Progresisas) y dibujar dos gráficos de barras apiladas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, con el control Cámara, creo imágenes vinculadas a dichos gráficos en otra hoja, para alinearlos a mi gusto y dar sensación de matriz. Lo bueno de esto es que si haces cambios en los gráficos originales, se reflejan en la imagen vinculada.

> [Mostrar dinámicamente el contenido de una celda o rango en un objeto
> gráfico](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/mostrar-din%C3%A1micamente-el-contenido-de-una-celda-o-rango-en-un-objeto-gr%C3%A1fico-e2e7a629-5662-42d6-9295-06d112c2099f)
>
> [La cámara fotográfica de
> Excel](https://exceltotal.com/la-camara-fotografica-de-excel/)

Luego quito bordes, quito eje vertical del secundario , desactivo la cuadricula (pon bordes blancos en las celdas) para que quede más limpio, etc.

Mi resultado final es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que esto se podría con dos "pantallazos" a secas de los gráficos pero claro, eso sería una imagen fija. Lo bueno del control Cámara es que si modificas los gráficos, tu imagen se actualiza porque se vincula y no tienes que estar haciendo nuevos pantallazos.

Te dejo tu archivo con los gráficos ya hechos, por si quieres cambiarlos. No es la mejor solución, es solo un apaño creo yo.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19GRt_ap3Yrda1jZIFXJ8TYAzXuSGbfUf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104533162415852069785&rtpof=true&sd=true

Un saludo.

Comment: agradezco mucho el tiempo que dedicaste a tu respuesta. Lo que hice finalmente fue algo parecido, aunque menos sofisticado: separar los datos y hacer un gráfico para cada panel... pero sin el retoque posterior.